# Android Studio Background Service to Update Location

Tags: java, android

I have this background service, which runs continuously even when the application closed (Paused or Stopped).

The service is to retrieve the user location and post it to server.

```
public class LocationUpdaterService extends Service
{
    public static final int TWO_MINUTES = 120000; // 120 seconds
    public static Boolean isRunning = false;

    public LocationManager mLocationManager;
    public LocationUpdaterListener mLocationListener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationListener = new LocationUpdaterListener();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!isRunning) {
                startListening();
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, TWO_MINUTES);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mHandlerTask.run();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopListening();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startListening() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);

            if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
        }
        isRunning = true;
    }

    private void stopListening() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public class LocationUpdaterListener implements LocationListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (isBetterLocation(location, previousBestLocation)) {
                previousBestLocation = location;
                try {
                    // Script to post location data to server..
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    stopListening();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            stopListening();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(), currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }
}
```

So, I figured to use a `Handler` to listen to `LocationListener` once every 2 minutes because I am assuming this is **saving more battery usage**.

But, I don't know if there's still any way I can improve my code so that:

1. It's saving much battery power
2. Memory friendly
3. The code is easier to read and maintain

Answer (score 3):

To save power you can use/implement a function to detect when the user is stationary. You can for example define a user in stationary state when the location has not changed in more than 2 minutes (set this parameter so it does not fire too often, as when the user stops at a red light). When stationary states are detected,  stop listen for location updates from the GPS and start listen for SIGNIFICANT_MOTION_SENSOR to detect active states. Be aware that not all models have this software sensor so you have to support situations when this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

One good approach is to request location updates in batch like this.
so you will be less frequently requesting for location updates:

> ```
> LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
> request.setInterval(10 * 60 * 1000);
> request.setMaxWaitTime(60 * 60 * 1000);
> ```
>
> In this case, location is computed roughly every ten minutes, and
>   approximately six location data points are delivered in a batch
>   approximately every hour. While you still get location updates every
>   ten minutes or so, you conserve battery because your device is woken
>   up only every hour or so.
>   [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/battery)

Answer (score -3):

What about location listener running in the background is'nt like two services running in the background .And you have minimum time update interval 0 .that will consume lot of battery